# Access "An error occured while Access was commnicating with OLE server"

Tags: ms-access, vba, ole

So I started with the Access contact database template and have been building up from there. There is a functionality in which by clicking on the ID number in the Contact List, it should call up the form to edit the details. I have made no changes to this code, and have even tried recopying it from the template from scratch.

However I am getting the error "A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control." It is telling me to restart the OLE server and try the operation again.

I have an old version of the database saved, and it runs fine over there. It just is something within my code here.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All of solutions I found online was not working for me.
Found that only rebuilding damaged form from scratch help me to solve this issue.
W10, Office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this error three times in my database.  Each time to fix it I simply just open a new blank project and import everything from your old project into your new project.

This might sound like a large undertaking basically you just go into the new project and select "Import Access Database".  Then just run through the wizard selecting everything in your current database. Click okay and let it run for a few minutes.

This has fixed it for me every time I have run into your error. I suspect it is just something to do with corruption.

Answer (score 0):

My programs also run into this error sometimes. 
I have recently noticed that the error most often occurs on *UNBOUND* forms (*forms without a RECORDSOURCE*).
What I have done most recently for these forms is the following:

1. Add "some" table (I usually take a Config table with just one record) as the RecordSource.
2. Compile the program code (this usually goes well, even before the fix!).
3. Save the form
4. Open the form. This should work fine now!
5. Remove the form's RecordSource, recompile and save again.
6. The form should still work fine!